# Найти точное значение в строке

Tags: php

Есть строка с числами. Каждое значение разделено запятыми.

Найти **21** в строке **12,33,32,443,21,335** можно было бы простым поиском, но цифры не уникальны и могут повторяться, к примеру:

```
   $int = '26,499,838,221';

   if(stristr($int, '21') == TRUE) {
     echo '21 найдено';   
   }
```

Найдет не 21, а 21 в 221. Как решить проблему? Использовать explode и проверять каждое значение?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте регулярные выражения:

```
$need = 21;
$str = '26,499,838,221';

if (preg_match("~\b{$need}\b~", $str)) {
    echo "Найдено $need";
}
```

---

Если точно известно, что числа разделены только запятой, то можно и с помощью explode():

```
$need = 21;
$str = '26,499,838,221';

if (in_array($need, explode(',', $str))) {
    echo "Найдено $need";
}
```